# C++ Redefinitions of macros and functions with 3rd party libraries

Tags: c++, libraries, glew, enet

I have a project which using a couple of 3rd party libraries. Among them it uses GLEW and ENet. When trying to compile the project it yields alot of errors about redefinitions of functions and macros. How can I solve this issue without changing the libraries? (I can't add namespaces to Enet because it is written in C)

Thanks in advance! Sorry for my bad english!

Edit:

Has requested in the comments I added the error and warnings list: http://pastebin.com/LiY8nHX6

Comment: Add the errors you get to the question.

Comment: Your errors make it seem like your program is including the Windows headers twice somehow. Can you show the `#include` lines your program uses?

Comment: It acually icludes serval classes which themselfs iclude more classes fomr another libraries, so evtually it probably include <windows.h> in both libraries somewhere. But that shouln't be a problem because all that #pragma once or the good old #define/#ifdef thingy.